# Grails: save is not working

Tags: grails, save

i have created new domain in grails and from a controller i've tried to save but nothing get saved in the database.. the code is as follow

> controller

```
     def register={
       String name = params.name
       String email = params.email
       String pass = params.password
       boolean signedIn = params.signedIn
       System.out.println(name + " " + email +" "+ pass+" " + signedIn)
       def rUser = new Registered(params)
      rUser.signedIn = signedIn

      System.out.println(rUser)
       rUser.save(flush:true)


   }
```

> domain

```
    class Registered {
    String name;
    String email;
    String password;
    boolean signedIn =false;


    static constraints = {

    }
}
```

and i'm trying to save by this url

http://localhost:8080/egypths/apps/register?name=hegab&email=eio@gmail.com&password=tom&signedIn=false

so what am i doing wrong ... putting in mind that there's no error in the stack trace

Comment: What do you get when you perform "println rUser.errors" after the save call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by wrapping this in an integration test that would look like this:

```
import groovy.util.GroovyTestCase
import org.junit.Test

public class RegisterControllerTests extends GroovyTestCase {

    @Test
    void saveAction() {
        def controller = new RegisterController() //or whatever the controller name is
        controller.params.name = "SomethingUnique"
        controller.params.email = "example@example.com"
        controller.params.password = "password"
        controller.params.signedIn = "false"

        controller.register()

        def registered = Registered.findByName("SomethingUnique")
        assert "example@example.com" == registered.email
        assert "password" == registered.password
        assert false == registered.signedIn
    }
}
```

Then I would start by making your controller action as simple as possible:

```
def register={
    String name = params.name
    String email = params.email
    String pass = params.password
    boolean signedIn = params.signedIn
    def rUser = new Registered()
    rUser.name = name
    rUser.email = email
    rUser.password = pass
    rUser.signedIn = signedIn

    rUser.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)  //I would remove the failOnError after you identify the issue.
}
```

This way you can quickly repeat your test and figure out where your problem is.  Adding the `failOnError:true` to the save call will cause an exception to be thrown if it doesn't pass validation.  If this simple example works start working back towards a more elegant solution to identify where you're issue resides.

Comment: Why failOnError in this case? Are you really recommending the error 500 page because the user typed an invalid password or omitted their email?

Comment: I would add the failOnError in an attempt to identify the issue.  I wouldn't leave it in there after I found the problem (probably should have specified that).

Comment: I set `failOnError=true` in Config.groovy, but in my code I always call `validate()` before saving. That way I only get a stacktrace for unexpected save failures.

Comment: Off topic but you could also simplify this further by removing all the assignments and having just `def rUser = new Registered(params)`, it will match up the property names for you and cut out a lot of unnecessary lines, see [Data binding](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/single.html#dataBinding)

Comment: @Steve Yes that would work, and the asker was previously doing that.  I only suggest breaking it out to get it working and then refactoring towards a more elegant solution like passing in the params.